# saving tables (e.g. latex) from Bayesian estimation functions in R

Tags: r, bayesian, stan

I would like to save the results of a Bayesian estimation function (e.g. `brm`) to file (e.g. in Latex format), for sharing results and preparing publications.  It appears that existing packages (e.g. `xtable`, `stargazer`) are designed with non-Bayesian statistics in mind and cannot handle these model objects.  Are there any existing packages or available code to handle this task (before I begin to recreate the wheel)?  I have found tools for making tables from models estimated using JAGS/BUGS [here](https://github.com/jkarreth/Bayes/blob/master/regression.table.R) but brm uses stan to estimate models.

Comment: I noticed a fantastic function for this in [this](https://stats.andrewheiss.com/donors-ngo-restrictions/Analysis/models-bayesian.html) blog post by Suparna Chaudhry and Andrew W. Heiss, but unfortunately it has not been made into a package (yet?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `launch_shinystan` on the object and go to the `Estimate` tab, there is a link to `Generate LaTeX table` that gives you a bunch of options to check on the left and it outputs the syntax on the right.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, for basic tables one may also access specific parts of the model by for example:

```
summary(model)$fixed
```

where `model` is a stanfit object, and pass that to xtable or another function to output latex tables.